# Data retrieve from PDF using Perl

Tags: perl-module

I would like to know the retrieve data from PDF using PERL. I have used the API::PDF but I'm expecting other than that. I am expecting data output like as PDF 2 DOC. I would be appreciate any one help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Writing a general PDF converter is not a simple task. There are at least two modules on CPAN which can help:

- CAM::PDF
- PDF::API2